# Angular Metadata ImportAs

Tags: angular, angular-components, reflect-metadata

Curious if anyone has or knows how to get more information regarding Angulars use of metadata? Specifically I am looking for what and where the importAs property is being used by Angular? It is created in the metadata when the angularCompilerOptions flag for flatModuleId is used. Based on what I can glean it seems that the compiler uses this to grab metadata about a module and/or a component when imported from a component lib in npm modules. Anywhere I can read more about this would be very helpful, thanks.